# POST in AJAX dont work when i redirect to the page

Tags: php, ajax, redirect, post

Hello im struggling with my Code :

I try to post some data to a php page :

```
$('.choixvol').click(function() {
    var id = "testid";
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'vol.php',
        data: {
            id: id
        },
        success: function() {
            window.location.href = "vol.php";
        },
    });
});
```

But when I redirect to my PHP page the `isset()` doesn't work :

vol.php :

```
<?php
require'header_fr.php';
logged_only();

if(isset($_POST['id'])){
    $id = $_POST['id'];
}else{
    $id = "not isset";
}
?>
<div id="container"class="container">
    <div class="form-wrap text-center">
    <?php echo $id ?>
    </div>
</div>
<?php
require'footer_fr.php';
?>
```

And display "not isset"

Comment: It's working properly. After redirect no data is passed in `$_POST`. `POST` data is passed only in **AJAX** request, redirect `window.location.href = "vol.php";` is **GET** request.

Comment: If you want to redirect to the same page you have just posted to, using ajax does not make a lot of sense; just post directly to `vol.php` instead using a form button.

Comment: Instead of window.location first test it with `alert()`

Comment: Why are you redirecting to the same page you make the ajax request? It's nonsense. Just post directly to the php script: `$('.choixvol').click(function() {var id = "testid";  window.location = ''vol.php?id=" + id;});` and then retrieve the value via **GET** or post using a form submit button.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get the id when you redirect to the page, pass it in via GET method (providing the id is not private and is ok to be viewed in the url).

```
$('.choixvol').click(function() {
  var id = "testid";
  $.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      url: 'vol.php',
      data: {id: id},
      success: function() { 
            window.location.href = "vol.php?id=" . $id;
        },
  }); 
});



<?php
require'header_fr.php';
logged_only();

if(isset($_POST['id'])){
    //Do something with your post ID when using the post method
}

if(isset($_GET['id'])){
    //Do something with your GET ID when redirected back with the GET method
    $id = $_GET['id'];
}
?>

<div id="container"class="container">
  <div class="form-wrap text-center">
  <?php echo $id ?>
    </div>
  </div>
 <?php
   require'footer_fr.php';
?>
```

Although the comments on the OP are correct, this method is nonsense.

Comment: Ok , the GET method work , but i will try using form button for a proper method.